# Derivation using Ito's Lemma of price process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma

Define $q(t)$ as the log price minus a linear trend

$$
 q(t) = \ln P(t) - \mu t
$$

Assume the log price process = Equation 1:
$$
  dq(t) = - \Theta q(t) dt + \sigma dW(t)
$$

Can you show that the solution to Equation 1 is:
$$
\ln P(t+h) - \ln P(t) = \mu h + (\exp(-h \Theta) - 1) \ln P(t) + \sigma \int_t^{t+h} \exp(-\Theta(t-u))dW_u
$$

Comment: Changed the term $\int^t_{t+h} \exp(-\Theta(t-u)dW_u)$ to $\int_t^{t+h} \exp(-\Theta(t-u))dW_u$, according to the original paper.

Answer (score 1):

by application of Ito's lemma , we have 
$$d\left(q(t)e^{\Theta\,t}\right)=\Theta \,q(t)e^{\Theta\,t}dt+e^{\Theta\,t}dq(t)+0$$
then
$$d\left(q(t)e^{\Theta\,t}\right)=\sigma e^{\Theta\,t}dW_t$$ 
in other words
$$q(t+h)e^{\Theta\,(t+h)}-q(t)e^{\Theta\,t}=\sigma\int_{t}^{t+h}e^{\Theta\,u}dW_u\Rightarrow$$
$$q(t+h)-q(t)=\left(e^{-h\Theta}-1\right)q(t)+\sigma\int_{t}^{t+h}e^{-\Theta\,(t+h-u)}dW_u$$
By substituting $\ln P(t)-\mu\,t$ to last equation , we have
$$
\ln P(t+h) -\ln P(t) =\mu h+\left(e^{-h\Theta}-1\right)(\ln P(t)-\mu t) + \sigma\int_{t}^{t+h}e^{-\Theta\,(t+h-u)}dW_u
$$

Comment: Hi - Why was it necessary to edit the question? I posted lnP(t+h) - lnP(t) not lnP(t) - exp(ho)lnP(t+h). You changed the entire question. I rolled it back. I am looking to see how its derived to the form I posted.

Comment: because it was wrong

Comment: I pulled it from this paper http://dx.doi.org/10.4236/tel.2012.23050  equation 2

Comment: You typed equation (2) incorrectly and I think that it is wrong

Comment: Is this paper really accepted?

Comment: From EQ(1) we get 
$$ \ln P(t) = q(t) + \mu t $$
Hence
$$ d \ln P(t) = dq(t) + \mu dt $$
Now put the solution for q into the equation and u'll get the result from the paper.

Comment: Indeed ,these are same.please check yourself

Comment: @Phun $$\ln P(t+h)-\ln P(t)=q(t+h)-q(t)+\mu(t+h)-\mu t\Rightarrow$$  $$\ln P(t+h)-\ln P(t)=q(t+h)-q(t)+\mu h $$

Comment: Just tried to point out the flaw in your original answer. You did a small mistake when substituting $$ \ln P(t) - \mu t$$ which let to an extra $$- \mu t$$ in the brackets on the RHS. Maybe I didnt get it clear enough in my response.

Comment: Thank u  , but I believe equation (2) is wrong